# Dynamic templates in Meteor

Tags: dynamic, meteor, templating

I have a question about dynamic templates in Meteor. I want to use a template multiple times with other data, but have no idea what I am doing wrong.
I have the following template:

```
<template name="knowyourcompany">
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2>Know your company</h2>
        </header>
        <p class="question">Q: {{question}}</p>
    </section>
</template>
```

I have the following template helper:

```
Template.knowyourcompany.helpers({
    knowyourcompany1: function(){
        return { question: "test" }
    }
});
```

And this is how I include the template

```
{{> Template.dynamic template="knowyourcompany" data=knowyourcompany1}}
```

The problem is that I see an empty template. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Template.dynamic` should be used if you want the template to be interchangeable, but in your case you want your data context to be interchangeable, so this is no use case for `Template.dynamic`. Instead, use the ordinary `{{> templateName myDataContext}}`:

```html
<template name="myMainTemplate">
    {{> myTemplate myDataContext}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.myMainTemplate.helpers({
    myDataContext: function(){
        return {a: 1, b: 2}
    }
})
```

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    a: {{a}}, b: {{b}}
</template>
```

Comment: By extension, I have asked this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682176/meteor-data-context-passing-array-into-each-spacebars-loop/27682405?noredirect=1#comment43779731_27682405 -- how does one insert many different data contexts?