# Meteor data context, passing array into each Spacebars loop

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

In this [Example 2](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#template-inclusion-ex-2) -- "**Passing a data context**"

**JS**

```
Template.overview.helpers({  
  users: [
    { name: 'David' },
    { name: 'Shaune' }
  ]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="overview">  
  {{> userList users}}
</template>

<template name="userList">  
  {{#each this}}
    {{name}}<br>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Result**

```
David  
Shaune
```

My goal is to pass an array of template names into `Template.overview` where users is, like so:

```
<template name="overview">  
  {{#each templateArray }}
    {{> userList this }}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Where `templateArray` is an array of strings with template names, and `this` is the name of each template.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

For more depth, consider that I have the following in my `helpers`

```
Template.overview.helpers({  
  users: [
    { name: 'David' },
    { name: 'Shaune' }
  ],
  otherUsers: [
    { name: 'Jane' },
    { name: 'Betty' }
  ],
  moarUsers: [
    { name: 'Ben' },
    { name: 'Jerry' }
  ]
});
```

And I'd like to pass each of these data context into the same template (in this case `userLists`).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call anything, you can use `this` inside helper, like

```
helper: function(){
   return this; //if you pass string via templateArray
   return this.name; //if you pass object via templateArray
}
```

Because what you do looks like this but is just wrapped nicely into templates

```
<template name="overview">  
  {{#each templateArray }}
      {{name}}<br>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I don't know why you have in code double loop, in first loop you pass object and it can't iterate throught it

## EDIT

If you wanna just loop throught array of strings, do:

```
{{#each templateArray}}
       {{this}}<br>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Goal is to render many templates (since they have unique data context in each case), thus supplying an argument to {{> userList }} was my assumption for this. The users helper is an array of objects, I have many of these arrays.

Comment: But you wanted to supply them with `this` which they have already, in your example above you can use `this.name` anywhere in userList template code or `{{name}}` anywhere in html